# The PHP HTMLPurifier library, but for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, htmlpurifier, html-sanitizing

Anyone who's done anything much with PHP and receiving rich-text input from something like TinyMCE has (probably) used something like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to keep the nasties out of the HTML you're intentionally allowing the user to submit.

For example, HTMLPurifier will take a string of (potentially malformed) HTML and strip out disallowed elements and attributes, try to fix broken HTML, and in some cases convert things like `<i>` to `<em>`.

Does anything equivalent exist for Rails (3)?  What's the generally accepted way to sanitize input from rich text editors in Rails so that you can output the unescaped HTML onto a web page and know that stuff like `<style>` and `<script>` tags have been taken out of it and it's not going to break your page (or steal your cookies!)?

EDIT | Anybody used [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/)?  Any other options with pro's & con's?

Comment: Try hpricot. https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sanitize method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize).

```
sanitize(html)
```

There is also a [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sanitize).

```
Sanitize.clean(html)
```

I tend to prefer the Sanitize gem because it can be used as a before_save filter in your models instead of having to use the sanitize method in each of your views.

Comment: Thanks!  You can actually invoke `sanitize` with `ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize("html here")` too, from inside a controller, not the model.